# Anyone got Logic 8 working with Lion?

Tags: macos, compatibility, logic

I know officially Logic 8 isn't compatible with Lion.

However, I know you can edit the plist (inside the package), or open it with terminal, to make it open under Lion. And it launches. (See [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15683608#15683608) on the apple discussion forums).

The question is, is it buggy, and do plug-ins work etc? - It would be great if someone who has tried this could post here!

Comment: Off Topic but I recommend you use Logic 9, it's way more stable and some features are awesome (compared to 8). It works fine in Lion.

Answer (score 2):

Logic Pro 8 uses some Carbon libraries. Carbon is no longer supported in Lion. That's why Logic Pro 8 is unstable running on OS X 10.7 Lion.

Answer (score 2):

As of the current version of Lion (10.7.2) the plist and Terminal tricks are unnecessary. It launches fine from the app icon and has been stable for me.

Whatever piece of the puzzle was missing, they apparently added it back to Lion in 10.7.2.  Woohoo!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need the terminal to start it, but I couldn't install it using the installer. The installer just told me that Logic Pro is not compatible with Lion. But I was able to simply copy Logic Pro 8 from an older Mac (go to filer -> applications and drag & drop to a USB stick and then again on Lion drag and drop it from the USB stick to applications.

It seemed to work fine, but I didn't test it a lot until now.